# Which Windows service controls screen brightness?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, services

Most of the laptops I've owned have been fine, however several Windows versions (including Windows 10) have had this occasional bug where the brightness controls will stop working when I wake the computer up from sleep. This results in the Brightness button in the Windows Tray not doing anything when clicked.

Rather than restarting the computer every time this happens, I'd like to know which service actually controls brightness so I can simply restart that instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too. A reboot fixes it, but I'd rather not have to shut everything down. (If a reboot does *not* fix it, you should reinstall your drivers.)

I tried restarting the `DisplayEnhancementService` as suggested in another answer. It didn't help. I also tried restarting the graphics driver with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. This didn't work either, but it's a good thing to try when your screen isn't turning on.

However, I was able to fix this issue on my laptop without a reboot by disabling my monitor:

Start Device Manager (I use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd>). Select "Show devices by type" in the View menu, and then find your device under "Monitors". On a laptop with no external displays attached, there should be only one. With the device selected, click the "disable device" button in the menu bar, and confirm in the popup dialog. This did not turn my display off when I tried it, but it flickered. Then enable the device again with the button. My brightness controls worked again at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Supporting Brightness Controls on Integrated Display Panels

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/supporting-brightness-controls-on-integrated-display-panels

but for your scenario, I suspect that display driver has something wrong, when PC awaken from sleep, system will re-load graphic adapter driver, if there is any issue occurred in this process, screen display will show some problems, such as brightness control not working problem.

Uninstall current graphic adapter and delete driver, download and install driver from manufacturer website.

Answer (score 0):

Go to
Task manager -> Services Tab -> find "DisplayEnhancementService" and right click on it and "restart"